# Перемещение ImageBrush (маски прозрачности) для Image

Tags: c#, wpf, opacity

Пошерстил интернет на данную тему и нашел примерно такую реализацию:

```
<Image x:Name="Image" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="205" Margin="97,105,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="281" Source="К чему применять маску.jpeg">
  <Image.OpacityMask>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Изображение, выступающие в качестве маски.jpeg"/>
  </Image.OpacityMask>
</Image>
```

Однако нужна возможность передвигать маску.
Как это можно сделать или как в качестве маски выбрать другое изображение(как элемент)?

Comment: Полагаю свойство [`Transform`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.media.brush.transform(v=vs.110).aspx) у [`ImageBrush`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.media.imagebrush(v=vs.110).aspx), но могу ошибаться

Comment: В частности использовать [`TranslateTransform`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.media.translatetransform(v=vs.110).aspx) в `Transform`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Свойство [`Transform`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.media.brush.transform(v=vs.110).aspx) у [`ImageBrush`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.media.imagebrush(v=vs.110).aspx), В частности использовать [`TranslateTransform`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.media.translatetransform(v=vs.110).aspx) в [`Transform`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.media.brush.transform(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
<Image Name="m_Image" Source="К чему применять маску.jpeg">
  <Image.OpacityMask>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Изображение, выступающие в качестве маски.png">
      <ImageBrush.Transform>
        <TranslateTransform X="100" Y="100"/>
      </ImageBrush.Transform>
    </ImageBrush>
  </Image.OpacityMask>
</Image>
```

Подробнее о трансформациях можно узнать в [этой](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/aa970500(v=vs.110).aspx) статье.

Однако добиться прозрачности у меня получилось только с png полупрозрачным файлом в качестве маски.

UPD: Изменение через код:

```
if ((m_Image.OpacityMask as ImageBrush)?.Transform is TranslateTransform)
{
  ((m_Image.OpacityMask as ImageBrush).Transform as TranslateTransform).X=110;
  ((m_Image.OpacityMask as ImageBrush).Transform as TranslateTransform).Y=110;
}
```

UPD: Изменение через привязку данных:

поскольку у [`TranslateTransform`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.media.translatetransform(v=vs.110).aspx) есть `DependencyProperty` [`XProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.media.translatetransform.xproperty(v=vs.110).aspx), [`YProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.media.translatetransform.yproperty(v=vs.110).aspx);

то можно назначать их с помощью [**привязки данных**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms750612(v=vs.110).aspx), например:

```
<TranslateTransform X="{Binding Something}" Y="{Binding Something}"/>
```

Comment: Можно ли изменять ***<TranslateTransform X="100" Y="100"/>*** не через XAML?

Comment: Добавил в ответ

Comment: Вижу, спасибо...